# Android OnApplyWindowInsetsListener / isAppearanceLightStatusBars / shared element transition bug on API 28

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

We have an app that currently uses `systemUiVisibility` to toggle the `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR` settings. As this is deprecated we want to move to using the new `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows` and `windowInsetsControllerCompat.isAppearanceLightStatusBars` instead. But we’ve hit a weird issue which seems to be a bug on API 28 — on API 29 we don't see the problem.

The app also has an `OnApplyWindowInsetsListener` on the root of our `Activity` layout to adjust for the IME being displayed, and between two of our `Fragment`s we use shared element transitions. Putting all of these together seems somehow to break layout, such that the `Fragment`’s root view gets set to width/height of 0.

[image: screenshot of layout inspector]

It’s the kind of thing that's easier to demonstrate than to explain, so I’ve made a very simple sample app to reproduce the issue, and put it [on github](https://github.com/jonathan-caryl/VanishingContent).

Here’s an animation of what happens — when we should see the second fragment again, we see nothing:

[image: animation of the issue]